# macOS Chrome: Cannot switch tabs by CMD + Shift + } when Chinese Input method is enabled

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ime, chinese

Cannot switch tabs by `CMD + Shift + }` or `{` when Chinese Input method is enabled.

I remember it was OK on macOS 10.11.

Answer (score 0):

Chinese keyboards use black lenticular brackets `【 】` instead of fullwidth square brackets `[]`. This is likely the *cause* of your problem. One solution is to use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between tabs (this also works on English keyboards).

Comment: This is the same as I guess. Is there any way to change to Half Angle of symbols?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: There are two type symbols, Chinese symbols like`【 “` and English `["`. em.. forget that question. Why is it working in Safari?